# Target table not updateable? Creating a sequence column with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I'm inputting the following query but getting an error message that the table is not updateble?

```
SET @rownumber = 0;
UPDATE (
SELECT _atc_codes.se, diagnoses.*
FROM diagnoses
JOIN _atc_codes
ON (_atc_codes.id = diagnoses.atc_code)
ORDER BY _atc_codes.se, diagnoses.year, diagnoses.county, diagnoses.age_group, diagnoses.gender) AS b
SET b.base_order_index = (@rownumber:=@rownumber+1)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to speed up my queries by adding a sequence column that I can sort my results on instead of sorting on multiple columns. It's based on an ORDER BY clause involving 5 columns, one of the from a JOINed table.

Comment: You want to update a temporary subquery. That won't work.

Comment: @juergend I tried using `UPDATE` with `ORDER BY`, but then I got error **"Incorrect usage of UPDATE with ORDER BY"**, so I saw someone suggesting this solution instead but it obviously doesn't work either.

Comment: are you trying to add a sequence column to a temp query, or to a table? YOu are apparently trying to do that on a query

Comment: @silkfire: Can you add example data and expected output to the quesion? I can't wrap my head around your query.

Comment: @juergend It's an auto-increment, based on the order of the results using my `ORDER BY` clause :)

Answer (score 0):

IF you are looking for an auto increment, follow the below example. If you don't care about the speed, just replace table with your subquery

```
SELECT mycols, @n := @n + 1 AS rownum
   FROM MYTABLE , (SELECT @n := 0) as rownumstart
```

to get with your order:

step1 add a rownum to join on

step2 update table by joining it with our subquery of same table in correct order, joining table.rownum with subquery.new_rownum

```
ALTER MYTABLE ADD rownum int (11) unsigned NULL DEFAULT NULL;

UPDATE MYTABLE ,

  (SELECT @n := 0) AS ALIAS
SET rownum=@n := @n + 1 ;


UPDATE TABLE
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT ordered.*, @n := @n + 1 AS rownum
   FROM
     (SELECT WITH your
      ORDER WITHOUT rid
      FROM TABLE) AS ordered,

     (SELECT @n := 0) AS ALIAS) ordered_with_rownum ON ordered_with_rownum.rownum=TABLE.rownum
SET TABLE.columnA=ordered_with_rownum.columnA,
          TABLE.columnB=ordered_with_rownum.columnB ....
```

Comment: I want the auto increment, but as part of a permanent table column, not in a SELECT statement.

Comment: try: ALTER MYTABLE  ADD rownum int (11) unsigned null default null;
update table, (SELECT @n := 0) set rownum=@n := @n + 1

Comment: You've missed the most relevant thing though, which is the specific order that I'm after.

Comment: easiest and fastest way though is to create table with auto increment, insert your data in the right order from original table, drop original table, rename new table. Much faster on processor as well. Not doable if you are using the table for a live app. Dropping and renaming a table should be done so fast nobody notices what happened :P